# How to render data from a buffer? React-Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, bluetooth

i'm new to react-native and i'm using the library react-native-ble-plx to connect a Heart Sensor to my app and show it's values.

At this point i managed to connect it via bluetooth and store the information on a buffer where i can see with console.log(buffer), as shown in next picture.

[image]

My question is how can i render this information to the application? I don't know how to handle it from that buffer.

edit: I specifically want the 2nd value of that buffer (the one that normally is 70)

Here is the code:

```
scanAndConnect() {
      this.manager.startDeviceScan(null,
                                   null, (error, device) => {
          this.info("Scanning...");

          if (error) {
            this.error(error.message);
            return;
          }
          console.log(device.name)
          //if (device && device.name == 'Inspire HR') {
            if (device && device.name == 'HX-00043494') {
            this.manager.stopDeviceScan()
             device.connect()
               .then((device) => {
                 this.info("Discovering services and characteristics ")
                 return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
           }).then((device) => {
                 this.info("Setting notifications")
            ``return this.Async_setupNotifications(device);
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.info("Listening...")
           return this.setupNotifications(device)

          }, (error) => {
            this.error(error.message)
          })
      }
    })`
  }


async Async_setupNotifications(device) {
 this.manager.characteristic  = device.characteristicsForService("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
console.log(buf);
console.log (buf[1]);


this.manager.characteristic.isNotifying = true;
this.manager.characteristic.isReadable = true;


 if (error) {
   this.error(error.message)
             }
return ;
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help so far

Comment: Have you tried something like this maybe? response.data[1] ? like entering the data field of the object and accessing the array's second place ([1]) and then saving this value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing console.log from within the application, you need to access the data via buffer.data[1], it should give you the second value.

If the `buffer` is a global variable, simple example how to render in React Native Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

let buffer;
export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {

    Async_setupNotifications = async (device) => { // call this method from within your code
       this.manager.characteristic  = 
       device.characteristicsForService("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
       const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
       console.log(buf);
       console.log (buf[1]);
       this.setState({pulse: buf.data[1]}); // assign the needed data to state
    }
    render() {
       return(
          <View>
              <Text>{this.state.pulse}</Text>
          </View>
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the function where i use the buffer is async so when i do <Text>{buffer.data[1]}</Text> it doesn't recognize the buffer, i tried passing it to other variable but i don't know how to do it. I tried storing it with setstate but without sucess so i tought there could be a way to just take that value out of the async function

Comment: Would you mind sharing a piece of relevant code? Hard to recommend anything otherwise.

Comment: Please don't post question edits as answers, there's an "edit" functionality on the question. I have updated my answer to get you started. Assuming that your code is correct, this should print the last reading. If you wish to preserve them all, you probably need to save everything in state as an array.